# Ajax request to Wikipedia API issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I want to make a simple request to the Wikipedia API:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: {
        action: "query",
        generator: "search",
        gsrnamespace: 0,
        gsrsearch: "te",
        gsrlimit: 30,
        prop: "info|extracts",
        inprop: "url",
        format: "json"
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: processResult
});
```

The outcome should look like this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=te&gsrlimit=10&prop=info|extracts&inprop=url

But this doesn't work properly from my ajax code.(there must be "extract" key).

I think the problem is in simbol "|" (look at ajax):

```
        prop:"info|extracts",
```

How to fix?

Comment: Nit: it's "Wikipedia" not "Wiki".

Comment: Thank you. I ve just made an edit

Comment: extracts is not always available !

Comment: thank you. I will handle that in the callback function. But please tell me how to cope with that vertical bar? Or there are other problems?

Comment: I solved this problem: but using getJSON with parameter "callback=?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: {
        action: 'query',
        generator: 'search',
        gsrnamespace: 0,
        gsrsearch: 'te',
        gsrlimit: 30,
        prop: 'info|extracts',
        inprop: 'url',
        format: 'json',
        origin: '*'
    }
}).done( processResult );
```

- uses plain AJAX instead of JSONP
- uses `origin: '*'` (which is required for that)
- uses HTTPS instead of HTTP (which won't work)

Not sure if this solves your problem because it is not very clear what your problem is...

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use getJSON instead of  $.ajax

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=te&gsrlimit=10&prop=info|extracts&inprop=url&format=json&callback=?", processResult);
```

2.Remember to add parameter with value(to avoid jQuery AJAX cross domain error)

```
callback=?
```

3.extracts are not always available